# I cant use any jquery ($ or document) inside of my node/javascript application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project and I am trying to use HTML, Javascript, and Jquery. I can not run any type of jquery code or even document.getElementById in my js file and I have no idea why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="app">
        <div>
            <form action="">
                <input id="searching" type="text" name="searching">
                <input class="submit-search" type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="tweets">
            <div id="tweet">
                <p id="text"></p>
                <p id="username"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/omarjandali/Desktop/LF_Backend/app.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
    at startExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:276:5)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:227:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: If you are trying to use it in node, you have to import it into node.  Though, given that you're not in a browser at that point, I don't really know why you would want to do that, since the primary reason to use jQuery is to smooth over differences between different browsers and different browser versions.

Comment: Your code as written will run just fine. I'm guessing you're actually trying to run jquery code on the server...

Comment: What I want to do is build a backend for a html page that will grab the data sent from the twitter api and then display it on the html page based on the users search in the search form. I want to use jquery to grab the string from the search and then send a request to the twitter api and use jQuery to display that information on the screen. @KevinB

Comment: jquery is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: how can i grab what is typed in the search directly in the  app.js file that will be used to send the string in the twitter api call @KevinB

Comment: You can't, that's not how any of this works. What is on the client is on the client, for the server to access it, the client would need to send it to the server.

Comment: So if I have a list of tweets that I have saved in an array, how can I display then onto the html file @KevinB

Comment: you can make it part of the html using a templating engine or simple string methods, or you can make it available to the client via an ajax request.